# My function is returning undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm testing a function, it just makes a calculation and and tests if it fits the criteria. It's returning `undefined` and I don't understand why. I've putted a `console.log(2)` just before `return true`, it logs the 2 to the console but doesn't return true. I'm new to JavaScript, please help.

```
const cenas = [
  [1, 150, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
  [2, 126, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
  [3, 99, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
  [4, 249, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
];
let nC = 4;
let nA = 2;
let soma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < nC; i++) {
  soma = soma + cenas[i][1];
}
let media = soma / nA;
let tolerancia = 0.5;
let nextStep = [1, 1, 2, 2];
let animador = 1;

const distribution = function(animador) {
  let indexes = [];
  let position = 0;
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; index >= 0; i++) {
    index = nextStep.indexOf(animador, position);
    position = index + 1;
    if (index >= 0) {
      indexes.push(index);
    }
  }
  let soma = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    soma = soma + cenas[indexes[i]][1];
  }
  let criterio = Math.abs((soma - media) / media);
  if (criterio > tolerancia) {
    console.log(0)
    return false
  } else {
    console.log(1)
    if (animador >= nA) {
      console.log(2)
      return true
    } else {
      animador++;
      distribution(animador);
    }
  }
}

console.log(distribution(animador))
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is an invisible line in the end of each function. It's `return undefined;` in case you forget to have `return` statements in all the different branches in your code.

If you used a proper IDE with coding standard settings such as airbnb it would tell you that `distribution` is broken since when `criterio > tolerancia === false` and `animador >= nA === false` it recurse, but nothing is done with the result. It is dead code.

Imagine you did `Math.abs((soma - media) / media);` instead of `let criterio = Math.abs((soma - media) / media);`. What good would it do?
Just as much as `distribution(animador + 1);` You need to use the result somehow, by setting it to a variable or returning it.

```js
return distribution(animador + 1);
```

Here is your code after fixing some points made by my WebStorm with ESLint with airbnb preset enabled:

```js
const distribution = function (animador) {
    const indexes = [];
    let position = 0;
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; index >= 0; i++) {
        index = nextStep.indexOf(animador, position);
        position = index + 1;
        if (index >= 0) {
            indexes.push(index);
        }
    }
    let soma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        soma += cenas[indexes[i]][1];
    }
    const criterio = Math.abs((soma - media) / media);
    if (criterio > tolerancia) {
        console.log(0);
        return false;
    }
    console.log(1);
    if (animador >= nA) {
        console.log(2);
        return true;
    }
    distribution(animador + 1);
    return undefined;
};
```

I haven't actually fixed the bug, but it is far easier to see it now.